# method or data member not found in vb6?

Tags: vb6

This is my code

```
Sub filllistview()
  Dim itmX As ListItem

  Main

  rs.Open " select * from hatw order by id desc  ", dbconn, 3, 2

  If Not rs.EOF Then
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
      Set itmX = ListView1.ListItems.Add(1, , rs!id)
      itmX.ListSubItems.Add , , rs!no_of_text
      itmX.ListSubItems.Add , , rs!date_of_text
      itmX.ListSubItems.Add , , rs!Title
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop
  Else
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
  End If

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> this error occurs:

> method or data member not found

The error highlights this statement:

> ```
> ListView1.ListItems.Clear
> ```

Comment: Maybe `ListView1.ListItems.Clear()` needs brackets?

Comment: I do it but this is error , thanks for your answer

Comment: Is `ListView1` in fact a `MSComctlLib.ListView`, or are you in a VBA environment?

Comment: yes I am in VBA environment , I think ListItem in MSComctlLib not ListView1 because when I write MSComctlLib. it appear a list that containt ListItem but not con tain ListView1

Comment: I think my error in adding component or references but I don't know which references or components should be add

Comment: What application is that? Where do you get `ListView1` from?

Comment: this is visual basic 6.0, ListView is a component on a tool box when you add to your form name of ListView is set to ListView1 , I retrive data from the database it is used to view data

Comment: I think the error in the library because when I make comment this statement ' ListView1.ListItems.Clear , same error occur at this statement Set itmX = ListView1.ListItems.Add(1, , rs!id) , when I write ListView1. after period alist appear but not contain ListItem

Comment: a Stone in the dark - are you sure it is a listview and not a listbox? Listview will give you the ListItems menu as where Listbox will only give you List. Also make sure, if it is a Listview, that the actual name Listview1 exist and is not named a different name.

Comment: I am sure bro, it's ListView not ListBox, and I am sure that the actual name is ListView1, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch about needing to add a reference to your project seems to be correct. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443482(v=vs.60).aspx) you need to add a reference to `MSCOMCTL.OCX`. In the Excel VBA editor reference dialog I had to search a bit for it (it wasn't a predefined reference) but found it on my machine at: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX`. Once I found the control it appeared as `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` in the reference list. Perhaps it is listed automatically as that already in Access. As soon as I added the reference lines like

```
Dim LV as ListView
```

compile cleanly.

Comment: Well now the OP reveals it's VB6 after all and not VBA. So having the component on the component toolbar is enough of a reference.

Comment: @GSerg Maybe you are right, but OP seems somewhat ambiguous on that point. They haven't been back in the 2 hours since their last comment. I'll delete this answer if they say it doesn't help them.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer but I don't have folder SysWOW64 and in the reference list I don't have Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6

Comment: @ghaziabdullah Maybe it is in the System32 folder. I qualified that part of the answer with "on my machine" with the understanding that it might be somewhere else on yours. Do a search for `MSCOMCTL.OCX`. It should be somewhere on your machine. Once you locate it, browse to it in the reference dialog box. I didn't have `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` on the list until *after* I set the reference.

Comment: thanks bro I founded , you are right I found in system32, now I will search to how to add to the reference list in vb6 , thanks very very much bro

Comment: In your project, right click on the left toolbar, select components. scroll down to Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) and select, click on ok and you're good to go. Listview will be added to your components.